# In ipyleaflet cannot access on_location_found attribute from SearchControl class

Tags: python, ipyleaflet

Working with ipyleaflet trying to get the latitude/longitudes from a successful location search using the `SearchControl` class. Running code from the ipyleaflet documentation [link](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controls/search_control.html?highlight=self._location_found_callbacks#). When I run the below example code in Jupyter I get the error `AttributeError: 'SearchControl' object has no attribute 'on_location_found'`. I know the code as it is won't get me what I need, but it was a starting point. Can anyone advise how I might be able to get the latitude/longitudes?

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, SearchControl

m = Map(center=[47, 2], zoom=5)

search = SearchControl(
    position="topleft",
    url='https://cartoradon.irsn.fr/commune.py/communes/search/FR/{s}?',
    zoom=5
)
m.add_control(search)

def on_found(**kwargs):
    # Print the result of the search (text, location etc)
    print(kwargs)

search.on_location_found(on_found)

m
```

Comment: `on_location_found`  only exists since version 15 of  ipylreaflet (see [ireleases](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/releases))

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: When trying to install ipyleaflet in conda it gives me version 0.12.3. ```conda install -c conda-forge ipyleaflet``` if i try adding in ```=0.16.0``` for the latest version it falls over.

Comment: Try with `pip  install`

Comment: Did that last night and its working. thank you. Feel free to add the comment above as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks again.